# discrete Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I generate a periodic discrete data representing a time dependent function and I want to apply a discrete Fourier transform to this data using just one period of it.

I think something is wrong with my Fourier transform code:

```
a = 0.05; L = 15; T = 20 \[Pi]; hdc = 2.1;
sol = NDSolve[{a*D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x] - Sin[u[t, x]], 
u[0, x] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == Tanh[t/0.01]*hdc, 
Derivative[0, 1][u][t, L] == 0}, u, {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, L}, 
MaxStepSize -> 0.005, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
q := NIntegrate[( 
Evaluate[First[Derivative[1, 0][u][tp, x] /. sol]])^2, {x, 0, L},
Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MinRecursion -> 50, 
MaxRecursion -> 100];
data = Parallelize[Table[q, {tp, 25.8, T, 0.5}]];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[data]]]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: On a core-i7 extreme it does not take much time to evaluate around 124 sec using `LaunchKernels[10]`. But its very memory hungry even with 64GB RAM I went more than 80% few times during the computation. But now I can offer the onlooker those plots ...

Comment: Guys,I do get the same result on my machine,but I think this Fourier analysis doesn't make sense,at least my supervisor says so.he says I have to tell the program that my function is periodic,so that the Fourier transform of it should go to zero for t infinity.

Comment: @AhmadSheikhzada Editting your code by involving [MemoryConstrained](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemoryConstrained.html) may help lots of people who would like to run your code! `:P`

Comment: @AhmadSheikhzada I am curious about the computational resources that are available to you. Could you please expand on that? Thanks!

Comment: @AhmadSheikhzada Did you consider plotting your DFT data using `MatrixPlot`. It makes it look neater. Here's my question as an [example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13045/204). Noted that I also used a Hard threshold value to obtain these plots.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your calculated data are correct, the first `ListLinePlot` shows what is an approximate delta-function, that is, a single isolated spike. The Fourier transform of a delta-function produces a flat spectrum, that is, a constant at all frequencies. Your second `ListLinePlot` of `Abs[Fourier[data]]` looks like a constant, plus or minus some noise. Thus, it looks fine to me...

Also note that the discrete Fourier transform assumes and induces periodicity of the input data, so you need not "tell the program that [your] function is periodic".